# How to take video stream from user's webcam, process it with c++ program and send back

Tags: flash, browser, webcam

I want to take video stream from user's webcam in web browser, process it with c++ program and send back. Can you give me same advise, link or code example?

Comment: Do you really need to use flash for this? Can't you use something else like OpenCV to deal with the camera and process the frames?

Comment: Send it back to who? The camera?

Comment: It will be nice to don't using flash, but how I can take and send video stream without it?